# Is it possible to set the package root for a Dartium launch?

Tags: dart, dartium

I'd like to be able to do this on a per-launch basis without having to set the global package root in Tools->Preferences.  Is this possible?

I see an 'arguments' option in the Dartium launch configuration, but that appears to be passing args to the browser, not the embedded VM?

Comment: Setting the package-root shouldn't really be necessary anymore. What's causing you to need it?

Comment: setting the package root manually comes in very handy in larger, more complex projects. One example of this is pointing a debug project to a project's package root, so that you can debug the project without having to perform a git commit/push/pull, pub update cycle.  I can achieve this easily enough by setting the global package root setting, but this becomes inconvenient with switching between projects often.  This is why I'm asking about a per-launch package root configuration via the editor for Dartium.  This can be achieved easily for VM projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the editor does not have support for setting package root for Dartium launches on a per launch basis. Dartium looks for the value for package root in the environment variable DART_PACKAGE_ROOT, it does not get passed in as an argument.

Comment: This is helpful.  At least I can deal with it from a script. Thanks!